# hibernate inheritance IDENTITY field

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, orm

I've got two similar classes to be stored in two seperate tables. I've got an abstract class named A. Two classes extends A, lets call them B and C.

I was thinking of using the Inheritance strategy InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS because it sweets well with my situation. However, it is not possible for me because I've got an Identity field in my primary key. Hibernate doc says that it is not allowed because each table shared there ID (or something like that ?).

I would like to know how can I store B objects in Table1 and C objects in Table2. B class and C class have exactly all same fields with an Identity field as primary key.

For example :

Table 1 :

{pk:0, environment:0, field:"aze"},{pk:1, environment:0, field:"dfg"},{pk:2, environment:0, field:"qsiu"} ...

Table 2 :

{pk:0, environment:1, field:"xcg"},{pk:1, environment:1, field:"zeg"},{pk:2, environment:1, field:"qsiu"} ...

Comment: have you tried define abstract method `getPK` in parent class, and override it in child one's with specified `PrimaryKey` annotation ? or even not abstract but mark as `Transient`

Comment: I don't understand how it will help in my situation ? I would like to have an IDENTITY field as primary key. Also is it possible to mark a method as Transient ?? What will it result ?